# Convert iSeries Date to String after setting it to 1st of next month

Tags: sql, date, db2

In a DB2 SQL query, I return two integers: year and month. From this, I need to construct a string of the format dd/mm/yyyy. The date must represent the first day of the NEXT month.

So for example
Year = 2016, Month = 9 would result in the string  "01/10/2016"

Currently I use the following (which I inherited) to do this:

```
substring(cast(DATE(INSERT(INSERT(LEFT(CHAR((Year * 10000) + (Month * 100) + 1),8),5,0,''-''),8,0,''-'')) + 1 month as char(10)),9,2)|| ''/'' ||
substring(cast(DATE(INSERT(INSERT(LEFT(CHAR((Year * 10000) + (Month * 100) + 1),8),5,0,''-''),8,0,''-'')) + 1 month as char(10)),6,2)|| ''/''||
substring(cast(DATE(INSERT(INSERT(LEFT(CHAR((Year * 10000) + (Month * 100) + 1),8),5,0,''-''),8,0,''-'')) + 1 month as char(10)),1,4)  as UPDATEDATE
```

but it seems horrible. Is there a better way to achieve this result?

Thanks

Ron Ventura

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 select VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(cast(year*10000+month*100+1 as char(8)), 'YYYYMMDD') + 1 month, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  as mydate                                         
 from yourtable
```